# Why this website shows currentMiliseconds value greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE?

Tags: date, datetime, unix-timestamp

The `MAX_VALUE` for Integer (32-bit) is , `2_147_483_647` and this is the maximum limit of time in the future (unless we switch to 64-bit Integers).

But [this](http://currentmillis.com/) website show current time in milliseconds equals to, `1_423_079_895_486`, and it shows the correct time.

How come the value is way too bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or maximum milliseconds value in unix time ?

Am I missing something basic ?

Comment: UNIX `timeval` structures contain two values -- seconds since the epoch, and milliseconds since the start of the second, separately stored. So even if you were on a system with a 32-bit width for seconds, anyone writing code to manipulate this return value would obviously use a larger/wider type to combine the two to get a single total milliseconds value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably just using 64 bits to represent the time in milliseconds.

This is unremarkable. The system I'm typing this on has a 64-bit `time_t` type.

Are you perhaps assuming that the C types `int` and `time_t` have to be the same size? They don't.  And a 32-bit number representing milliseconds can only span a duration of just under 50 days.

We don't even know how the web site is implemented; it could well be using some scripting language with support for variable-width integers.